# Can the counter be expanded so plays above 999 are counted?

Tags: draw-something

The counter stops at 999. Does anyone know how to get the counter to count above 999?

Comment: When the game was released, the counter was stuck on 99, this was changed in a later patch, so I'm betting the only option to go past the 999 limit is to wait for a patch

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the user cannot do anything in their power to change this. As johnoboy mentioned, the only solution would be an update/patch from the developers.

Comment: Can anyone tell me when a patch will bereleased on yhe counter problem?